# how to update my custom table after execution of rules

Tags: hooks, rules, database

i have created a table as follow

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Implements hook_schema
 */
function core_sms_schema() {
  $schema['core_sms_details'] = array(

    'description' => 'This table is used to keep track of sms sent/failed on specific date.',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => 'The primary identifier for a node.',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'date' => array(
        'description' => 'Date',
        'mysql_type' => 'TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'sms_sent' => array(
        'description' => 'The SMS sent on particular date.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '0',
      ),
      'sms_failed' => array(
        'description' => 'The SMS failed on particular date.',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => '0',
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;
}
```

After a sms has been sent i have to update the columns with number and date. i already have rules also but not able to get how to update the custom table using rules.

Answer (score 0):

In rules you have option to add PHP code inside the **Action ->PHP-> "Execute custom PHP code** " in that have a code to update the custom table.

The following variables are available and may be used by your PHP code:

**Variable name Type    Description**

**$site**   Site    Site information

**$node**   Content updated content

**$node_unchanged** Content unchanged content

you can use for updating the table if its a node

Note : here node represented as a example

Comment: but the table which i am going to update is not node table. its a custom table.

Comment: yes Shridhar in custom table what content are you going to update ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i am going to store sms counts datewise. for example:Today how much sms sent by me and how many sms failed.